# Adding arguments to ASP.NET MVC 5.0 Controller Method Causes JQuery Datatable Ajax Call to Hang

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Exactly as read in the title. For some reason, changing my controller method to accept parameters causes my DataTable ajax call to this method to fail.

Function signature

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public JsonResult LoadPayoffAgingGrid(/*string SearchText, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate*/)
```

DataTable call:

```
function LoadPayoffAgingReportGrid() {

    var wsUrl = '@Url.Action("LoadPayoffAgingGrid", "Report")';
    var dtStart = $('#dtStart').val();
    var dtEnd = $('#dtEnd').val();
    var sSearch = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();

    oTableLoansView = $('#PayoffAginggridtable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": wsUrl,
        "iDisplayLength": 50,

        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sDom": sDomStandard,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "sDateStart", "value": dtStart });
            aoData.push({ "name": "sDateEnd", "value": dtEnd });
            //aoData.push({ "name": "sSearch", "value": sSearch });
        },
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [
                { "sName": "BorrName", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignleft hidden-xs" },
                { "sName": "LoanNumber", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignleft" },
                { "sName": "SubdivName", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignleft hidden-xs" },
                { "sName": "LotNum", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "pointer hidden-xs" },
                { "sName": "OpenDtAge", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignright" },
                { "sName": "AgeGroup", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignright hidden-xs" },
                { "sName": "PaidOffDt", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignright" },
                { "sName": "CommitmentAmt", "bSortable": true, "sClass": "alignright" },

        ],
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
    });

}
```

Could anyone explain what causes MVC and Jquery Datatables to interact like this? I'd imagine it's a facet of AJAX, which I don't understand very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discerned that the issue was there is no implicit conversion between `DateTime` and `null`. The other functions work perfectly well because they lack parameters of type `DateTime`. The solution is to make these parameters nullable, as below:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public JsonResult LoadPayoffAgingGrid(string SearchText, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
```

Comment: pretty much what i meant when i said if you have non-nullable parameters then they are required.  making them nullable makes them optional...

Answer (score 1):

if you add non-nullable parameters you need to include them in your request

`DateTime StartDate` and `DateTime EndDate` is required  and your request seems to be sending `sDateStart` and `sDateEnd` which would throw an error since the parameter names do not match

Comment: Those parameters are stored in the request's HttpContext, and not passed as arguments. I have other methods in this same controller that work perfectly without the arguments being passed in the typical way of using the `data` param.